# Добавляемые View не отображаются на экране внутри Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

У меня есть некий `Fragment`, который содержит в себе `ScrollView`, а внутри него `LinearLayout`, на который добавляются исходящие и входящие сообщения:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:gravity="fill"

android:background="#D1EDF6">

<TextView android:text=""
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/tvChatterName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvChatterName"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llChatBottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/chatListLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Сам `Fragment` представляет собой класс, который сначала считывает историю сообщений, выводит её на экран, а следом за этим запускает `IntentService`, который постоянно обращается к базе и передаёт в `BroadcastReceiver` сообщение, если есть новые. Я его отлавливаю и вывожу новые сообщения на экран.
При первом запуске фрагмента всё работает идеально, сообщения выводятся и корректно отображаются. После чего я выхожу и вновь захожу в чат, заменяя фрагмент следующим образом:

```
public void openFragment(Fragment fragment){
    this.fragment=fragment;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Замена происходит корректно, чат открывается, считывает историю сообщений, выводит её на экран. После этого вновь запускается сервис, но, когда приходит новое сообщение, хотя оно и корректно обрабатывается (тем же способом, что и создание сообщение при считывании истории), при добавлении её на `LinearLayout` его не видно на экране.

Проверка `LayoutParams` показала, что они такие же, как и у корректных сообщений. В самом `LinearLayout` новые сообщения отображаются, вместе со всеми параметрами. Создание новых `View` проводится через `LayoutInflater`, я подозреваю, что проблема может быть в нём, но не вижу в чём. Сейчас я делаю inflate так:

```
if(getActivity() != null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                sendView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send, null);
                sendContent = (TextView) sendView.findViewById(R.id.sendContentText);
                sendTitle = (TextView) sendView.findViewById(R.id.sendTitleText);
                sendDate = (TextView) sendView.findViewById(R.id.sendDateText);
                sendAvatar = (ImageView) sendView.findViewById(R.id.sendAvatarImage);

                sendTitle.setTextSize(10);
                sendContent.setTextSize(9);
                sendDate.setTextSize(9);
            }
```

Добавляю я эти вьюшки на этот `Layout`, определяемый в `onCreateView()`:

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container,
            false);
    chatListLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chatListLayout);
```

Я пробовал делать `inflate` для `sendView`, указывая в качестве `parent` параметра `Layout`:

```
sendView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send, chatListLayout, null);
```

Также пробовал по-разному получать `LinearInflater`, но результат остаётся прежним.

Добавление на `Layout` проводил также несколькими способами, через простой `addView()` и `addView()`, явно указывая `LayoutParams`, но это не возымело какого-либо эффекта.

Надеюсь, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и сможет помочь понять, что происходит такого, что вьюшки теряются в пустоте.

Comment: А почему кстати вы не используете listview/recyclerview? В том смысле, что врядли кто-то встречался с этой проблемой кроме разве что авторов виджетов.

Comment: @YuraIvanov в начале пути мне этот способ казался более простым, не пришлось писать адаптер. Но, как оказалось, он привёл к подобным бедам. Я уже подумывал о переходе на listview, но надеялся, что смогу решить проблему.

Comment: Задача может быть и интересная (в академическом смысле), но учитывая опыт оригинальных разработчиков, потративших время на всевозможную оптимизацию списков, написание адаптера на два экрана максимум, имхо, не выглядит каким-либо оверхедом.

Comment: @YuraIvanov я уже переделал с использованием ListView, и всё заработало, но изначально это казалось проще. Возможно, сказывается недостаток опыта работы с ListView